# Vagrant: How to paste text in Windows command window, when running Vagrant ssh

Tags: windows, vagrant

How can I copy and paste stuff into Windows command window, which runs Vagrant ssh in it? Right mouse button is then somehow blocked

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The windows terminal is awful.  To paste, what you need to do is right-click the top-left corner of the window (where the icon is), go down to edit, and select "Paste".  No keyboard shortcuts for it.

Now, one alternative is to connect to your vagrant VM with something like Putty.  Just connect to localhost on port 2222.  username is "vagrant" but you will need to take a few steps to convert the SSH key for login.  [Here](https://github.com/Varying-Vagrant-Vagrants/VVV/wiki/Connect-to-Your-Vagrant-Virtual-Machine-with-PuTTY) is an article explaining what you need to do.

Answer (score 1):

An easiest shortcut would be:

**1) Go to your vagrant vm**

-> vagrant ssh

**2) Set password to your vagrant user**

sudo passwd vagrant

Enter new UNIX password: 12345

Retype new UNIX password: 12345
passwd: password updated successfully

**3) Login using Putty :**

Host name: localhost  Port: 2222 (or your vagrant vm mapped ssh port)

username: vagrant

password: 12345

Enjoy!

Answer (score 1):

On Windows 10:

1. Right-click on the terminal menu title.
2. Click `Properties`
3. Check `Options` > `Edit Options` > `Use Ctrl+Shift+C/V as Copy/Paste`

Answer (score 0):

Supplement.
I use the git ssh key for ssh.(I use the laravel homestead)

So when load the key in putty key generator, you should choose the git ssh private key.